# How to get an environment variable value into Dockerfile during "docker build"?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm building a container for a ruby app. My app's configuration is contained within environment variables (loaded inside the app with [dotenv](http://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)).

One of those configuration variables is the public ip of the app, which is used internally to make links.
I need to add a dnsmasq entry pointing this ip to 127.0.0.1 inside the container, so it can fetch the app's links as if it were not containerized.

I'm therefore trying to set an `ENV` in my Dockerfile which would pass an environment variable to the container.

I tried a few things.

```
ENV REQUEST_DOMAIN $REQUEST_DOMAIN
ENV REQUEST_DOMAIN `REQUEST_DOMAIN`
```

Everything passes the "REQUEST_DOMAIN" string instead of the value of the environment variable though.
Is there a way to pass environment variables values from the host machine to the container?

Answer (score 586, accepted):

You should use the [`ARG` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) in your Dockerfile which is meant for this purpose.

> The `ARG` instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time to the builder with the docker build command using the `--build-arg <varname>=<value>` flag.

So your *Dockerfile* will have this line:

```
ARG request_domain
```

or if you'd prefer a default value:

```
ARG request_domain=127.0.0.1
```

Now you can reference this variable inside your Dockerfile:

```
ENV request_domain=$request_domain
```

then you will build your container like so:

```
$ docker build --build-arg request_domain=mydomain Dockerfile
```

**Note 1:** Your image will not build if you have referenced an `ARG` in your Dockerfile but excluded it in `--build-arg`.

**Note 2:** If a user specifies a build argument that was not defined in the Dockerfile, the build outputs a warning:

> [Warning] One or more build-args [foo] were not consumed.

Comment: ARG is available from docker v1.9 onwards.

Comment: is this supported to be built remotely on docker repo?

Comment: ```Your image will not build if you have referenced an ARG in your Dockerfile but excluded it in --build-arg``` you are wrong. You can build image with references even without --build-arg. Moreover you can set default value for the build arg.

Comment: What is the purpose of the ENV line?  For me --build-arg + ARG was enough.

Comment: The ARG defines a variable to be used inside the dockerfile in subsequent commands. The ENV defines an environment variable which is passed to the container.

Comment: Why is there `=` in `ENV request_domain=$request_domain`? I thought the syntax would be like `ENV request_domain $request_domain`. BTW, correct me if I am wrong, but why doesn't `ENV request_domain=$request_domain` (or `ENV request_domain $request_domain`) just work? Isn't it passing the value of `request_domain` to docker?

Comment: This will not work for AWS_REGION environment variable

Comment: Please note that while on both Windows and Linux, the Dockerfile itself will expect variables with the `$var` syntax... When using `RUN` commands on Windows, cmd will still expect the `%var%` syntax and powershell will still expect the `$env:var` syntax.

Comment: I think you want to point the build command at a directory, like `.`. Not `Dockerfile`. At least, that's what worked for me, and is what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43297404/1196465

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216766/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array-issue-facing-in-ku?noredirect=1#comment127596994_72216766 Please help me to sort this out

Answer (score 70):

This is for those looking to pass env variable from **docker-compose** using `.env` file to **dockerfile**  during build and then pass those args as env variable to container.
Typical docker-compose file

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY
        - DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL
        - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```

Pass the env variable present in `.env` file to args in build command.
Typical `.env` file

```
SECRET_KEY=blahblah
DATABASE_URL=dburl
```

Now when you run docker-compose up -d command, docker-compose file takes values from .env file then pass it to docker-compose file. Now Dockerfile of web containes all those varibales through args during build. Now typical dockerfile of web,

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ARG SECRET_KEY
ARG DATABASE_URL
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_BUCKET
ARG AWS_REGION
ARG CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN

ENV CELERY_BROKER_URL redis://redis:6379/0
ENV CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND redis://redis:6379/0
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true
ENV SECRET_KEY  ${SECRET_KEY?secretkeynotset}
ENV DATABASE_URL ${DATABASE_URL?envdberror}
```

Now we recieved those secret_key and db url as arg in dokcerfile. Now let's use those in `ENV` as `ENV SECRET_KEY ${SECRET_KEY?secretkeynotset}`. Now even docker container has those variables in it's environment.
*Remember not to use `ARG $SECRET_KEY`(which I did). It should be `ARG SECRET_KEY`*

Comment: It does not work
`The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services.web: 'args'`

Comment: @MaximColesnic your args should be under build section, and not under web which your error says. So args is under services.web.build. Watch your indentations.

Comment: Thank you for this very hard to find information. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: thanks for this well defined answer

Comment: Please help me to sort this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216766/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array-issue-facing-in-ku?noredirect=1#comment127596994_72216766

Comment: Saved the day! Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with docker-compose 3.7. ``` jetty:
        build: jetty
           args:
              - CURRENT_PROFILE=$CURRENT_PROFILE
              - ENV_CONFIG_PATH=$ENV_CONFIG_PATH```

It shows and error - mapping values are not allowed here in 'reader', line 20, column 16: args: ^

Answer (score 69):

So you can do:
`cat Dockerfile | envsubst | docker build -t my-target -`

Then have a Dockerfile with something like:

```
ENV MY_ENV_VAR $MY_ENV_VAR
```

I guess there might be a problem with some special characters, but this works for most cases at least.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you need to ADD files from the directory containing the Dockerfile.

Comment: Very nice solution! On a Mac you can get `envsubst` as part of `brew install gettext`. But because of possible conflicts with the BSD build system it is "keg-only" and no symlnks are made. However, it is safe to do `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/*/bin/envsubst /usr/local/bin/` to add that one command to your PATH. (It's really the libs that are the concern.) Or you can use it in its `/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/*/bin/envsubst` location

Comment: To clarify @TomHennen's comment, piping the Dockerfile to `docker build -` is, specifically, what doesn't work when you reference relative paths from your Dockerfile, regardless of env var substitution.

Comment: Re @TomHennen's comment, if you _do_ want to use context-dependent commands like COPY in your Dockerfile you could always redirect the output of envsubst to a temporary file and then feed that into `docker build` instead. Example: `cat Dockerfile | envsubst > DockerfileWithEnvVars`, then `docker build -t my-target -f DockerfileWithEnvVars .`, then `rm DockerfileWithEnvVars`

Comment: Or you can use sponge from moreutils package ```envsubst < Dockerfile | sponge Dockerfile```

Comment: Adding `-f` before `-` seem to fix the issue with the `ADD` command not working: `cat Dockerfile | envsubst | docker build -t my-target . -f -`

Comment: If you per the instructions of @ALex_hha use sponge, you'll overwrite the original Dockerfile. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Please help me to sort this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216766/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array-issue-facing-in-ku?noredirect=1#comment127596994_72216766

Answer (score 24):

An alternative using `envsubst` without losing the ability to use commands like `COPY` or `ADD`, and without using intermediate files would be to use Bash's [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
docker build -f <(envsubst < Dockerfile) -t my-target .
```

Comment: unfortunately that does not seem to work (Docker 17.09), I get the error `unable to prepare context: the Dockerfile (/dev/fd/63) must be within the build context`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216766/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array-issue-facing-in-ku?noredirect=1#comment127596994_72216766 Please help me to sort this out

Answer (score 17):

Load environment variables from a file you create at runtime.

```
export MYVAR="my_var_outside"
cat > build/env.sh <<EOF
MYVAR=${MYVAR}
EOF
```

... then in the Dockerfile

```
ADD build /build
RUN /build/test.sh
```

where test.sh loads MYVAR from env.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. /build/env.sh
echo $MYVAR > /tmp/testfile
```

Comment: Remember to give permissions to the shell file. with `chmod 775 env.sh`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216766/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array-issue-facing-in-ku?noredirect=1#comment127596994_72216766 Please help me to sort this out

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to find and replace all environment variables ($ExampleEnvVar) in a Dockerfile then build it this would work:

`envsubst < /path/to/Dockerfile | docker build -t myDockerImage . -f -`

Comment: Best answer here, and based on that, was able to do: `envsubst < ./Dockerfile | docker build -squash -t ${DOCKIMG}:${VERSION} . -f -` where the `FROM` line is using the environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

When using `build-arg`...

> `docker build --build-arg CODE_VERSION=1.2 Dockerfile`

...consider that the variable is not available after `FROM`:

```
ARG  CODE_VERSION=latest
FROM base:${CODE_VERSION}
```

> An `ARG` declared before a `FROM` is outside of a build stage, so it can’t be used in any instruction after a `FROM`.

Generally `ARG`s should be placed after `FROM` if not required during `FROM`:

```
FROM base:xy
ARG  ABC=123
```

> To use the default value of an `ARG` declared before the first `FROM` use an `ARG` instruction without a value inside of a build stage:

```
ARG VERSION=latest
FROM busybox:$VERSION
ARG VERSION
RUN echo $VERSION > image_version
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Comment: Also worth noting: "To use an argument in multiple stages, each stage must include the ARG instruction."

Answer (score 2):

You can directly pass env variables when container start :

```
docker run -e [your_variable_name = your_variable_value] [image to instanciate]
```

Example :

```
docker run --rm -e TARGET=192.168.1.9 ubuntu env
```

The output is :

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=36399469e519
TARGET=192.168.1.9
HOME=/root
```

The target variable was added to your env variables of the current container !

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I wrong.
The question was about env variables - not about args. The question was How to send ENV var to container - it means that container can reference to that variable. So I think the answer should be the following:

1. there is no need to use ARG cos it is used only during building the image
2. if you need to pass environment variable to container there is syntax that can be used to run the container:
   `docker run --name [container-name] -e "[variable-name]=[new-value]" [image-name]`

Answer (score -3):

add `-e` key for passing environment variables to container. 
example:

```
$ MYSQLHOSTIP=$(sudo docker inspect -format="{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" $MYSQL_CONRAINER_ID)
$ sudo docker run -e DBIP=$MYSQLHOSTIP -i -t myimage /bin/bash

root@87f235949a13:/# echo $DBIP
172.17.0.2
```

Comment: Damien is looking to build an image. -e works with the run command instead.