# Can we pass ENV variables through cmd line while building a docker image through dockerfile?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, boot2docker, dockerfile

I am working on a task that involves building a docker image with **centOs** as its base using a **Dockerfile** . One of the steps inside the dockerfile needs **http_proxy** and **https_proxy** ENV variables to be set in order to work behind the proxy.

As this Dockerfile will be used by multiple teams having different proxies, I want to avoid having to edit the Dockerfile for each team.  Instead I am looking for a solution which allows me to pass ENV variables at build time, e.g.,

> sudo docker build -e http_proxy=somevalue .

I'm not sure if there is already an option that provides this.  Am I missing something?

Comment: what is the problem with passing those at run time? Something like `docker run -e http_proxy http://1.2.3.4:3128 -e https_proxy 1.2.3.4:3129`? The doc of  `docker run` http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: The problem is that one of the steps inside docker file invovles yum installation and it fails if i dont set the http/https ENV variables and without proper installation i can't build the image .so **docker run** doesnt help me here .

Comment: I am afraid you will have to build specific images, the only difference being the values of http_proxy(s) ONBUILD may help, but I am afraid it is not suited here, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/

Comment: This have been discussed here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4962 and again here https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9176 and closed, so at the moment, it seems you have no solution

Comment: Thank you user2915097 for your comments .I have already gone through the above github links ,I asked this question  with a tiny hope that someone on Stackoverflow might have faced this similar situation.

Comment: Please feel free to chime in at https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9176 to add your requirements for something like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get environment variable value in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537645/get-environment-variable-value-in-dockerfile)

Answer (score 205):

Containers can be built using `build arguments` (in Docker 1.9+) which work like environment variables.

Here is the method:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
ARG APP_ENV=local
ENV APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
RUN cd /usr/local/etc/php && ln -sf php.ini-${APP_ENV} php.ini
```

and then build a production container:

`docker build --build-arg APP_ENV=prod .`

For your particular problem:

```
FROM debian
ENV http_proxy=${http_proxy}
```

and then run:

`docker build --build-arg http_proxy=10.11.24.31 .`

Note that if you build your containers with `docker-compose`, you can [specify these build-args in the `docker-compose.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/args), but not on the command-line.  However, you can use [variable substitution in the `docker-compose.yml` file, which uses environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/variable-substitution).

Comment: Because I overlooked it: You need ARG to tell docker that a build argument can be passed to the builder. Without specifying ARG <name> it doesn't work.

Comment: This `ENV APP_ENV ${APP_ENV}` is not needed. It's enough to have `ARG APP_ENV` without `=local` and it will grab build argument and use it as any variable set by `ENV`

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo That's true during the build, but `ARG` isn't persisted as an environment variable when the docker image is ran.  Using `ENV APP_ENV ${APP_ENV}` ensures that the environment variable is still available when the container is running.

Comment: @DuckPuppy true but I sticked to the OP's question

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo OP's question is about passing `ENV` from command-line, so how does having `ARG` alone help? You need `ARG` so that you can pass one via `--build-arg` and then you need `ENV` to copy it to an environment variable to be persisted with the image.

Comment: @haridsv OP's question is about passing `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` urls at build time and providing ready to use Dokcer images for different teams using different proxies. Value passed via `ARG` would be stored in a proper configuration file in the image without the need to take it again from `ENV` on container creation. Normally you would use `ENV` for configuration which is intended to be set on container creation, and a combination of `ARG` and `ENV` for settings with default values which can be overriden on container creation.

Comment: Values passed via `ARG` will not be available at the time of container creation.

Comment: yes, yes, 1000 time yes. This was the exact answer i needed. I know it's pointed out in the other comments about, but YOU MUST SPECIFIC THE ARGUMENT IN THE DOCKERFILE. Don't forget that.

Answer (score 54):

So I had to hunt this down by trial and error as many people explain that you can pass `ARG` -> `ENV` but it doesn't always work as it highly matters whether the ARG is defined before or after the `FROM` tag.

The below example should explain this clearly. My main problem originally was that all of my ARGS were defined prior to `FROM` which resulted all the `ENV` to be undefined always.

```
# ARGS PRIOR TO FROM TAG ARE AVAIL ONLY TO FROM for dynamic a FROM tag
ARG NODE_VERSION
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

# ARGS POST FROM can bond/link args to env to make the containers environment dynamic
ARG NPM_AUTH_TOKEN
ARG EMAIL
ARG NPM_REPO

ENV NPM_AUTH_TOKEN=${NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}
ENV EMAIL=${EMAIL}
ENV NPM_REPO=${NPM_REPO}

# for good measure, what do we really have
RUN echo NPM_AUTH_TOKEN: $NPM_AUTH_TOKEN && \
  echo EMAIL: $EMAIL && \
  echo NPM_REPO: $NPM_REPO && \
  echo $HI_5
# remember to change HI_5 every build to break `docker build`'s cache if you want to debug the stdout

..... # rest of whatever you want RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT etc..
```

Comment: WOW, dang, happened to me too! No one is speaking about this, nowhere in the docs a mention, warning etc!

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Might I mention this was critical if your deployment environment is from automatic CI. IE I found this when I was trying to make gitlab CI to scale across project domains. IE One project might be settling one different node versions etc...

Comment: Saved me some nerves, thank you! I would never figured out that placement of ARGs matters..

Comment: I think this is actually explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact): `An ARG declared before a FROM is outside of a build stage, so it can’t be used in any instruction after a FROM`

Comment: Thanks so much, what an annoying problem to track down, cheers

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same situation.

According to Sin30's answer pretty solution is using shell,

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "cd /usr/local/etc/php && ln -sf php.ini-$APP_ENV php.ini"]
```

Answer (score 3):

To set multiple build arguments like in your case for **http_proxy** and **https_proxy** you've to do the following changes:

1). Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:latest

# Define ARG after FROM to indicate values coming from build arguments are part of the build stage.
ARG http_proxy 
ARG https_proxy

# Create the environment variables and assign the values from the build arguments.
ENV http_proxy=$http_proxy \
    https_proxy=$https_proxy \

# Print the values.
RUN echo "http_proxy: $http_proxy"
RUN echo "https_proxy: $https_proxy"
```

2). Command to run

```
sudo docker build \
--build-arg http_proxy=http://172.0.0.1 \
--build-arg https_proxy=https://10.20.30.2 \
.
```