# Pass environment variables in a file to Dockerfile during build time

Tags: docker

Is it possible to pass environmental variables as a file to a Dockerfile at the time of building a docker image?

I have used `--build-arg` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198835/can-we-pass-env-variables-through-cmd-line-while-building-a-docker-image-through) but as I have multiple arguments would prefer to use a file with all.

Also I have tried using `docker run --env-file=mydata.env` approach as well but I need to add these parameters during build time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pass a build arg in to a build using the `docker build` command is with the `--build-arg` argument. There isn't support for specifying multiple build args from a file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification