# Docker ft. .env no cooperation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm working on a dynamic DockerFile which can communicate with an .env document. I created this regarding a good local environment for my development team. They use Docker Desktop and create their Docker Dev environment with a Docker-Compose, DockerFile and .env configuration.

Only once I run it inside the Docker Desktop application, everything seems to be fine, it only stops at the part inside the DockerFile when they are depending of the .env document.

DockerFile top part:

```
# Use a dummy base image
FROM alpine:latest AS dummy

# Define base image
# LANGUAGE: Programming language to use for development (Default: php)
ARG LANGUAGE

# LANGUAGE_VERSION: Language version
ARG LANGUAGE_VERSION

# WEB_SERVER: Web server
ARG WEB_SERVER

# Import environment variables from docker-compose-dev.env
ENV LANGUAGE=$LANGUAGE \
    LANGUAGE_VERSION=$LANGUAGE_VERSION \
    WEB_SERVER=$WEB_SERVER

# Define base image
FROM ${LANGUAGE}:${LANGUAGE_VERSION}-${WEB_SERVER}

RUN if [ -z "${LANGUAGE}" ]; then \
        echo "Error: LANGUAGE argument is missing"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi

# Install required packages and dependencies
```

My .env example:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------
#           Docker Compose Configuration
# --------------------------------------------------------

# Programming Language Configuration
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Programming language to use for development
# Options: php, flutter
# Default: php
LANGUAGE=php
# e.g.
```

My Docker-Compose example:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    env_file:
      - .env
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${WEB_SERVER_PORT}:${WEB_SERVER_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ${APP_SOURCE_CODE_PATH}:${CONTAINER_WORKDIR}
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
    networks:
        - mynetwork
    init: true
```

Some parts are missing regarding arguments, but I only share with you guy's the examples, not the full argument list.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean with "stops"? Stops doing what? Does it print messages or crashes silently?

Comment: It gaves me the following error: echo "Error: LANGUAGE argument is missing";

Comment: What's the exact problem you're running into?  I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve with that Dockerfile; wouldn't it be easier to just write the base image you need into your application's Dockerfile?  Your container with `entrypoint: [sleep, infinity]` does nothing and you might consider removing it from the setup.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll remove it. The problem currently is. It can't read the .env file once I run the DockerFile

Comment: Ahh... That makes more clear. I'll try thanks! Sadly that I can't use it inside Docker Desktop.

Comment: It should be possible to build your image using docker compose, I did a quick check on SO which led me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545644/16034206 and then I checked the official docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/) which suggests ways to build using compose such as specifying dockerfile and then defining args to pass to the dockerfile (use placeholders to read from .env and pass as args), or dockerfile_inline to specify your build inline (i suspect you can use the placeholder to read from .env here. I havent done it, so I cant confirm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I need to present the environment and arguments inside the docker compose and only make use of .env, otherwise the docker compose didn't saw it.