# Docker how to inject host ENV into Dockerfile ENV during build?

Tags: docker

I am adding some environment settings on docker repo automatic build, lets say, `WEBSERVER_PRIVATE_KEY=123`

in my Dockerfile, when I build locally, I assume it would pick up the env value

```
RUN echo $WEBSERVER_PRIVATE_KEY > /somewhere/key
```

But it didn't work.

I had a look at the `ENV` command, but it doesn't seem there is a way to inject that value.

I had a look at the `ARG` command, but it requires to pass as `--build-arg` which I doubt it will work during built on docker repo.

See below environment settings on docker repo during automatic builds, how do I make the Dockerfile to reference the `WEBSERVER_PRIVATE_KEY` in the setting.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get environment variable value in Dockerfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537645/get-environment-variable-value-in-dockerfile)

Comment: I have seen that one, but I am not sure if it's duplicate, well, I am not sure if docker's build actually passes the environment values from repo settings as build arguments.

Comment: Is this Docker Cloud or Docker Trusted Registry?

Comment: It's docker cloud

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this on selective environment variables, but you need to pass them with the `--build-arg` and configure your Dockerfile to receive them. When you don't give a `--build-arg` a value for the variable, or an environment variable a value with `docker run -e` on running, Docker will use your environment to set the value.

Here's an example Dockerfile that uses the build-args:

```
FROM busybox

ARG DOCKER_HOST=${DOCKER_HOST:-""}
ENV DOCKER_HOST=${DOCKER_HOST}

CMD echo "DOCKER_HOST is ${DOCKER_HOST}"
```

If you do your build and pass `--build-arg DOCKER_HOST`, docker will set that variable from your environment:

```
$ echo $DOCKER_HOST
127.0.0.1:2376

$ docker build --build-arg DOCKER_HOST -t test-env:latest .
...
Successfully built 088fabdd9a96

$ docker run test-env
DOCKER_HOST is 127.0.0.1:2376
```

If you do the build without the arg, that environment variable won't be passed:

```
$ docker build -t test-env:latest .
...
Successfully built ef31d886749b

$ docker run test-env
DOCKER_HOST is
```

But you can still manually pass it from your environment on a `docker run -e DOCKER_HOST`:

```
$ docker run -e DOCKER_HOST test-env
DOCKER_HOST is 127.0.0.1:2376
```

Comment: this answer has brought me enlightenment after 1 day of going around in circles. Thank you @Bmitch

Answer (score 2):

The docker build process doesn't happen in your local environment. That's why variables your local shell variables aren't picked up.

When you `docker build .`, all of the files in the dir where your Dockefile resides are copied to the docker daemon host (whatever your DOCKER_HOST points to). The build steps happens at that point. So yes you either need to pass variables using ARGS, or do copy your local environment variables into a file which will be copied to the docker host as part of the build context.

Remember to make use of the `.dockerignore` to specify dirs/files which should not be copied to the build context. That speeds up build time specially for remote docker hosts.

For Docker for Mac/Windows, the `DOCKER_HOST` is not defined but the same behaviour takes place. Your local files (build context) is built on a very small Linux like OS (Xhyve) that's running in your Mac.

Comment: I am completely aware that's my local environment, my question is about when I add the environment settings on the repo on docker.

Comment: Sorry but your comment isn't clear to me. Are you asking "how" to add environment variables to the host that will be used to build from the context?