# Docker build gives "unable to prepare context: context must be a directory: /Users/tempUser/git/docker/Dockerfile"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that is supposed to build an Ubuntu image. But whenever I run

```
docker build -t ubuntu-test:latest ./Dockerfile
```

it shows the following error on the console

> unable to prepare context: context must be a directory: /Users/tempUser/git/docker/Dockerfile

I'm on Mac OsX. I tried to `sudo` as well. Nothing works.

Comment: I find it interesting that none of the answers explain *why* it doesn't work, especially when the [`docker build` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files) specifically says it will: "Instead of specifying a context, you can pass a single Dockerfile in the URL" and "If you use `STDIN` or specify a `URL` pointing to a plain text file, the system places the contents into a file called `Dockerfile`, and any `-f`, `--file` option is ignored. In this scenario, there is no context."

Answer (score 245, accepted):

You need to point to the **directory** instead. You must not specify the dockerfile.

`docker build -t ubuntu-test:latest .` does **work**.

`docker build -t ubuntu-test:latest ./Dockerfile` does **not work**.

Comment: why is it like this? it seems strange to need to point to a dir when you could easily have it point to the file itself

Comment: Per a below answer from @JakubKnejzlik, you can point to a file using the `-f` flag (then still refer to a directory, usually using `.`, so docker still has the context it wants)

Comment: Still get error: `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/kes/work/projects/sidnet/chimera/Chimera-DevEnv/Chimera/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 126):

You can also run docker build with `-f` option

`docker build -t ubuntu-test:latest -f Dockerfile.custom .`

Comment: This worked for me. Dockerfile name in my case was **Dockerfile-abcd** so I had to fire: `docker build -t my-custom-name -f /path_to_my_docker_file/Dockerfile-abcd .`

Answer (score 29):

## Understand contexts

#### The `docker build` command

The basic syntax of docker's build command is

```
docker build -t imagename:imagetag context_dir
```

#### The context

The context is a directory and determines what the docker build process is going to see: From the Dockerfile's point of view, any file `context_dir/mydir/myfile` in your filesystem will become `/mydir/myfile` in the Dockerfile and hence during the build process.

#### The dockerfile

If the dockerfile is called `Dockerfile` and lives in the context, it will be found implicitly by naming convention.
That's nice, because it means you can usually find the Dockerfile in any docker container immediately.

If you insist on using different name, say "/tmp/mydockerfile", you can use `-f` like this:

```
docker build -t imagename:imagetag -f /tmp/mydockerfile context_dir
```

but then the dockerfile will not be in the same folder or at least will be harder to find.

Comment: What if my Dockerfile doesn't neet any context?  In my use case, the folder I want to store the Dockerfile in contains other large files that just slow down the Docker build process.

Comment: @WolfLink In that case you should put your Dockerfile into an empty directory. You may not like it much, but that is the Docker folks' design decision.

Answer (score 18):

To specify a `Dockerfile` when build, you can use:

```
docker build -t ubuntu-test:latest - < /path/to/your/Dockerfile
```

But it'll fail if there's `ADD` or `COPY` command that depends on relative path. There're many ways to specify a `context` for `docker build`, you can refer to [docs of docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for more info.

Comment: Did this for *ubuntu 12.04* :
```docker build -t ubuntu:12.04  - <  Dockerfile```
You must be in the root of the *Dockerfile*

Answer (score 6):

I face the same issue. I am using `docker version:17.09.0-ce`.

I follow below steps:

1. Create Dockerfile and added commands for creating docker image
2. Go to directory where we have created Dockfile
3. execute below command `$ sudo docker build -t ubuntu-test:latest .`

It resolved issue and image created successsfully.

Note: build command depend on docker version as well as which build option we are using. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, whenever Docker build is run, docker wants to know, what's the image name, so we need to pass -t : . Now make sure you are in the same directory where you have your Dockerfile and run

`docker build -t <image_name>:<version> .`
Example 
`docker build -t my_apache:latest .` assuming you are in the same directory as your Dockerfile otherwise pass -f flag and the Dockerfile.

`docker build -t my_apache:latest -f ~/Users/documents/myapache/Dockerfile`

Comment: In order to get that second command to run for me I had to change it slightly: `docker build -t my_apache:latest -f ~/Users/documents/myapache/Dockerfile` (note the addition of a `.` at the end)

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons for me getting an error was the file name make sure the file  name is
**Dockerfile**
So i figured it out, hope it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is, I created a docker file named 'Dockerfile' inside a folder, and when inside the folder I ran `sudo docker build .` (notice the dot at the end of the command, dot means current folder)