# Docker Symlinks Not Woking On Fresh Install

Tags: docker

I am a complete noob to Docker, I apologize if this a simple question, I seem to have a significant installation/configuration error in Docker.  I am working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57.

I am literally trying to follow [the basic Docker tutorial for beginners from their website](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) and the second command is not working.

The tutorial is no big deal, I can switch tutorials to something more up to date, but it seems that key functionality of Docker is not working correctly.. symlinks.

This command `docker build -t getting-started .` results in this error:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/<user>/Downloads/WebDev/Docker/tutorial/getting-started-master/app/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

I double & triple checked everything.  I literally tried every solution found here:
[Docker: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511604/docker-unable-to-prepare-context-unable-to-evaluate-symlinks-in-dockerfile-pat?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)
[Docker build gives "unable to prepare context: context must be a directory: /Users/tempUser/git/docker/Dockerfile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43296019/docker-build-gives-unable-to-prepare-context-context-must-be-a-directory-use)

Nothing worked.  I could only execute the command using an explicit path. rather than "." which is going to get annoying pretty quickly when developing real projects.

`docker build -t getting-started ~/Downloads/WebDev/Docker/tutorial/getting-started-master/`

All documentation states `docker build -t getting-started .` is the correct command, so I am worried about continuing with a "broken" docker installation.

I ran the docker `./check-config.sh` script and it shows all is well except `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: missing`   which I thought was inconsequential for the moment since hello-world image worked as expected.

Hhhmmm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What directory are you in when running these commands? From your error it seems you are in the /app directory, whilst you should probably be 1 directory up.
Or, alternatively, your dockerfile is 1 directory below where it was intended to be. I draw this conclusion by comparing the 2 paths you mention:

```
~/Downloads/WebDev/Docker/tutorial/getting-started-master/app/Dockerfile
```

vs

```
~/Downloads/WebDev/Docker/tutorial/getting-started-master/
```

If the second one works, then the dockerfile is under `getting-started-master` and not under `/app`.

Fyi: Docker has a context and unless you explicitly specify it to be something different, by default it's going to be the directory the Dockerfile is located in.

Comment: Appreciate the reply.  You helped me see a silly "user error"... after extracting the zip for the tutorial, I didn't change the name of the extracted directory from "getting-started-master" to "getting-started", hence `docker build -t getting-started .` command got thrown off.  Simple mistake, I wish they mentioned. oh well.. thanks. Let the learning continue. :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped you in that respect. Learning is essentially the process of making mistakes in order to do things better next time, so it was a good lesson :) .