# Pass host environment variables to dockerfile

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, centos7

How can I pass a host environment variable (like user and hostname) to a dockerfile?

For example, if my username is `taha`:

```
echo $USER
taha
```

How do I write my Docker file to get the same output?

```
FROM centos:centos7   
ARG myuser=$USER  
CMD echo $myuser
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get environment variable value in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537645/get-environment-variable-value-in-dockerfile)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue. My solution was to provide the variable inside of a docker-compose.yml because yml supports the use of environment variables.

In my opinion this is the most efficient way for me because I didn't like typing it over and over again in the command line using something like `docker run -e myuser=$USER . . .`

Declaring `ENV myuser=$USER` will NOT work, in the container, `$myuser` will be set to `null`.

So your docker-compose.yml could look something like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
       - "myuser=${USER}"
```

and can be run with the short command `docker-compose up`

To check that the variable has been applied, run `docker exec -it container-name printenv` to list all variables in the container.

Comment: I guess I need to use Docker-compose, I m new to this, I try it and tell if it works, hopefully it does :)

Answer (score 6):

When you start your docker container you can pass environment variables using the `-e` option like so:

```
docker run -it <image> -e USER=$USER /bin/bash
```

Comment: Great, what to do when you ENV var is a path to a very sensitive file in your host machine (don't want to copy the file to the container)?  Create a volume to access the file?

Comment: You can simplify that to `docker run -it <image> -e USER /bin/bash`

Comment: @hzitoun yes, depending on your situation, mount it for access

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use-case where I wanted to be able to specify a version for the image. This has a slight extra requirement that you must specify the [`ARG` before the `FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).

First we specify `IMAGE_VERSION` in the `Dockerfile`, as per the question I'm also including a `USER` arg that we can pass in too:

```
# give it a default of latest
# declare the ARG before FROM
ARG IMAGE_VERSION=latest
FROM centos:${IMAGE_VERSION}
ARG myuser  
CMD echo $myuser
```

Then, as from the Docker compose docs on [`args`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args):

> Add build arguments, which are environment variables accessible only during the build process.

You can add these in your `docker-compose.yml` for example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        "myuser=${USER}"
        IMAGE_VERSION
```

Then as long as you have `IMAGE_VERSION` set in your environment it will be passed through.

Answer (score -4):

you need to use the `ENV` setting in your dockerfile

`ENV myuser=$USER`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Comment: FROM centos:centos7 ENV myuser=$USER CMD echo $myuser but it doesn't print the username

Comment: This won't take the value of $USER from the host machine.