# Docker. How to set 3rd party environment variable in a NodeJs container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to set an Oracle environment variable inside the container.

I believe it is not running, because the files are not available on the OS.

Could anyone help?

Thank you so much

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
COPY ./ /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/app/instantclient_21_5:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

CMD [ \"npm\", \"run\", \"start\" ]
```

When running the bash container. I try to run commands from the environment variable. Unsuccessfully.

Comment: I guess you have to use a docker-compose file. A user had a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440492/pass-host-environment-variables-to-dockerfile. Take a look at icc97's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to set an environment variable in a `RUN` statement doesn't make any sense: the commands in a `RUN` statement are executed in a child shell that exits when they are complete, so the effect of `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH...` aren't visible once then `RUN` statement finishes executing.

Docker provides an `ENV` directive for setting environment variables, e.g:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
COPY ./ /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/app/instantclient_21_5

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

Note that this can only be used to set static values (that is, you cannot include the value of another environment variable in the value -- you can't write `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/app/instantclient_21_5:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). That should be fine because in this situation `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should initially be unset.

(Also, you need to stop escaping the quotes in your `CMD` directive.)

Comment: The bit about using environment variables in an ENV statement is incorrect. You can do `ENV PATH=/my/path:$PATH` for instance.

Comment: In fact that won't do what you want: there is no `$PATH` defined in the current environment (or if there is, it has nothing to do with the container image you're building). You would typically want to do something like that at *runtime*, because you want the value of `$PATH` *as it is defined inside the container*.

Comment: I'm not the OP, if that's not clear. I just reacted to you saying that you can't use environment variables in ENV statements which you absolutely can.

Comment: That was clear, and I was pointing out the fallacy in your previous comment. That example doesn't make sense, and doing that generally won't give people the behavior they expect.

Comment: It gives me exactly what I expect. I'm not wise enough to speculate on what other people expect.