# docker: pass arguments to entrypoint

Tags: docker

If I have a super-dumb dockerfile, like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENTRYPOINT echo
```

Is it possible to pass arguments to the ENTRYPOINT, so that it will print whatever argument I pass?  I tried `docker build -t test . && docker run test foo` but I just got an empty line.

Comment: I would recommend a combination of arguments and/or environment variables, [as this SO answer outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537645/get-environment-variable-value-in-dockerfile/34600106#34600106). You can specify default values if you like. Your `ENTRYPOINT` line should allow you to make use of an env var.

Comment: Is it possible to directly do the thing I'm asking about, or do I need to use a different solution?

Comment: I don't own the Dockerfile in question

Comment: If you can't edit the Dockerfile, you may wish to build a new Dockerfile off of the original one; assuming it's build specific. Otherwise you next best option may be to override the entrypoint during your docker run, such as `docker run --entrypoint="<your new entrypoint>"`. Here's [the documentation from Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime).

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the image and fix the entrypoint:

```
FROM user_name/image_name
ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]
```

Or override the entrypoint:

```
docker run --entrypoint=echo user_name/image_name Hello World
```

Either way you don't need to be the owner of the `Dockerfile` you mention as long as you have access to the image.

Comment: I don't own the dockerfile. I'm trying to find a way to do it from the command line

Comment: Either extend the image or override the entrypoint via arguments of `docker run` then.