# DockerFile and environment variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

According to this:
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

I can set the MySQL root password with:

`docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag`

I assumed that `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` would be an environment variable that's set using `ARG` (e.g. [Get environment variable value in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537645/get-environment-variable-value-in-dockerfile) ) however, looking at the DockerFile (https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/696fc899126ae00771b5d87bdadae836e704ae7d/8.0/Dockerfile ) I don't see this `ARG`.

So, how is this root password being set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually used in the entrypoint script -
Ref - https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/696fc899126ae00771b5d87bdadae836e704ae7d/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh

Entrypoint config in Dockerfile -

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh # backwards compat
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify a bit about parameters in Dockerfile.

ARG - is only available during docker image build. 
Let’s say, you want to store in docker image a hash commit of you source code.

```
ARG Commit
```

than you build a docker image:

```
docker build -t someimage —build-arg Commit=<somehash>
```

ENV - values that are available for docker containers and can be used as a part of RUN command.

On actual runtime, you can change ENV variable or add new env variables by adding it to run string:

```
docker run -e SOME_VAR=somevar someimage.
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How does this answer the question?