# Get env variables from script and pass to Dockerfile

Tags: bash, shell, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have a **script.sh** like that

```
DATE="R_$(date +%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S)"
export DISTDIR="$BUILDDIR/$DATE"
```

and i wan't to pass this DISTDIR in my **Dockerfile** like that

```
COPY build/$DISTDIR/ "$CATALINA_HOME"/webapps/ws/js/
```

How i do that, i searched for various modes and none worked

Comment: Don't work for me

Comment: Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: I do not want to set a variable in docker run, I just want to get the variable set in script.sh and pass as parameter to my Dockerfile

Comment: Where does `script.sh` run? Inside Docker or outside?

Comment: **script.sh** was an example, but on occasion he would be outside Docker

Comment: Then I think you may have skimmed the question too quickly. It's true that their use case is setting a variable, but the question asked and answered is how to *get* a variable defined in a script that invokes `docker build`, and to use its value inside the Dockerfile.

Comment: I understand the question, it's exactly what I want but it uses **dotenv** and I do not, because my **DISTDIR** variable will not be static, it will be dynamic ... with each build my it will change, if there is a way I can only change the **DISTDIR** variable From the script.sh to an .env file, yes it would be useful to ask, since my script.sh file contains much more information than the **DISTDIR** variable, but the only one I will pass to the **dockerfile** is it

Comment: An environment variable is an environment variable. It doesn't matter if you set it with `export var=value` or `declare -x var=value` or `source myfile.env`.

Comment: I tried the solution and it hangs at the time of COPY build / $ DISTDIR / "$ CATALINA_HOME" / webapps / ws / js / until I give a Ctrl + C to stop the build

Comment: Does `RUN echo "Copying $DISTDIR"` show the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is passing the environment variable, not how you set it (dotenv or not) or how you use it (to set a variable or COPY).

Here's a complete demo with the technique [from the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537645/get-environment-variable-value-in-dockerfile). This is `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mycustomvar="file.$RANDOM"
touch "$mycustomvar"
echo "I am running outside Docker with mycustomvar=$mycustomvar"
docker build --build-arg mycustomvar="$mycustomvar" .
```

And a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine
ARG mycustomvar
RUN echo "I am running in docker with mycustomvar=$mycustomvar"
COPY $mycustomvar /tmp/
RUN ls /tmp
```

Here's what happens when you run it:

```
$ sudo ./script.sh
I am running outside Docker with mycustomvar=file.10518
Sending build context to Docker daemon  17.41kB
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine
 ---> 3fd9065eaf02
Step 2/5 : ARG mycustomvar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a6dfa6001164
Step 3/5 : RUN echo "I am running in docker with mycustomvar=$mycustomvar"
 ---> Running in e958044bfd11
I am running in docker with mycustomvar=file.10518
 ---> 95c107e49291
Removing intermediate container e958044bfd11
Step 4/5 : COPY $mycustomvar /tmp/
 ---> d36445b49261
Removing intermediate container e3ac014d1ba9
Step 5/5 : RUN ls /tmp
 ---> Running in 590409a81df5
file.10518
 ---> d734f83cc8ec
Removing intermediate container 590409a81df5
Successfully built d734f83cc8ec
```

As you can see, `script.sh` sets a variable, and the RUN and COPY statements both have access to it.

Comment: after many attempts I got ... as I had said the script.sh was an example where there were more scripts involved, and the error was in the passage of variables among these scripts, but finally I did, thank you very much, you helped me very much