# Use System Environment Variable in Docker Container C#

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-web-api

I am running my webapi project in docker container and I am unable to use environment variable set on my machine. Can I use System's Environment variable on running container. Thanks In Advance

```
var env = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("kubes");
var env2 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("kubes");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variables on the host machine are not available inside the Docker container, but it's possible to pass them in when starting the container:

```
docker run -e "deep=purple" -e today my-image
```

`-e` will set an environment variable inside the container. In the example the first option will set the environment variable `deep` with the value `purple`, while the second will set the variablle `today` with same value as the `today` variable has on the host machine. E.g. if `today` is set on your machine, it will also be set inside the container with the same value; it effectively passes it on.

Docker docs: [click](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

Comment: Can i set this option in my docker file?

Comment: You'll have to pass in the environment variables as build args and then assign them with ENV. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34600106/1339804