# How to using env variables in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

1. How to using env variables in Dockerfile?
2. not args

This is my Dockerfile now:

```
FROM node:12
```

I want Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:$version
```

How can I do it? If it is not possible, then I will create a feature request for Docker.

Comment: That's exactly what `ARG` is designed for.  There is no way to transparently get an environment variable from the host; you must explicitly pass it as a build argument.  [Get environment variable value in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537645/get-environment-variable-value-in-dockerfile) says more.

Comment: @DavidMaze but I have a prod.env file, how can I pass all the variables from it to all stages of the Dockerfile build? help please = (

Comment: Usually you'd use an option like `docker run --env-file` to specify those settings at deploy time, and build your image against a fixed set of software.  Ideally you run the exact same image in dev, QA, and production (and you wouldn't change the base version of Node between environments).

Comment: @DavidMaze no, this is NOT runetimу variables, is variables like graphql endporint, rate limit, e.t.c. FOR WEBPACK. webpack is a ON OF multi part of stages build. This it NOT runtime variable =( its compile html files and script with ENV VALUES. its not runtime =(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add as `ARG`s under a different place from the `ENV` variables. You can use them in the compose, just a little differently.

`ARG`s will be used during the build ***only***, if you need them to available for the build & ***again*** while running the container for some reason you will have to set **both** an `ARG` as well as an `ENV` variable. {{{During the `Build` stage they will be **called in the *exact* same manner**}}}. ENV are set to replace defaults when running a container, so the build's `ENV   TZ=Europe/London` will be replaced by the Compose's `Environment: TZ=America/New_York`

```
services:
  my_node_version:
    image: my/node
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ../node.Dockerfile
      args:
        - VERSION=12
        - NEEDED_IN_BUILD_AND_RUN=SomeStrangeUseCase
    environment:
      - ONLY_USED_IN_IMAGE=MyImageWorks
      - NEEDED_IN_BUILD_AND_RUN=SomeStrangeUseCase
      - OVERRIDE_BUILD_ENV="Will replace the ENV from the Build"
```

I'm pretty sure that fulfills all the ***intent*** from the question (you asked to not use `args` I assume because you wanted them set in the `docker-compose.yaml` rather than the dockerfile). You can do this, you just have to set them in a different way.

`ENV` ***cannot*** be used in the build from the Compose (`ENV` variables set in the Dockerfile just set the ***defaults*** that the container will use ***if*** none are declared in the OS, the Compose, or anywhere Docker gets them from), so that simply isn't a possibility, so if you **need** it to be `ENV` specifically for some reason then the answer is simply "You can't" end of discussion. But I don't see anything that could possibly accomplish, & no reason using ARGs wouldn't accomplish **exactly** what you want. You just need to place them in a different section, but they should function as needed