# docker-compose file doesn't pick up environment variable from a dedicated env file causing the seeding of database to fail

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

### Host System

- **Windows 10 Pro**

### Software

- Docker Desktop for Windows 10
- `docker --version Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d`
- `docker-compose --version docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c`

### Scenario

Provide the following:

- I wish to seed a MongoDB Container with some pre-defined JSON data that I have.
- I am aware it is possible to insert data using `mongoinsert`
- I wish to create a stack of the database and other apps dependent on it and seed the data  upon bringing this stack up

### Repository Structure

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── mongo_seed
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── factors.json
│   └── filters.json
└── .env
```

#### Code Snippets

within the `mongo_seed` directory the following `Dockerfile` exists:

```
FROM mongo:3.6.21

COPY factors.json /factors.json

COPY filters.json /filters.json

# ASSUMING THIS INFORMATION COMES FROM docker-compose file
ARG database_uri
ENV DATABASE_URI=$database_uri


CMD mongoimport --uri $DATABASE_URI --collection factors --drop --file /factors.json --jsonArray

CMD mongoimport --uri $DATABASE_URI --collection filters --drop --file /filters.json --jsonArray
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file in the root is as follows:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
    # MongoDB
    mongo:
        container_name: mongodb
        image: mongo:latest
        env_file:
            - .env
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        networks:
            - "qualiexplore_net"

    # Initial Seed to QualiExplore Database
    mongo-seed:
        env_file:
            - .env
        build:
            context: ./mongo_seed
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                database_uri: ${DATABASE_URI}
        networks:
            - "qualiexplore_net"
        depends_on:
            - mongo

networks:
    qualiexplore_net:
        external: true
```

`qualiexplore_net` is created externally via

```sh
docker network create qualiexplore_net
```

The `.env` file is a dummy file:

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=qualiexplore
DATABASE_URI=mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/qualiexplore
```

### Errors

#### Standalone Build

The build within the `mongo_seed` directory produces no problems when I execute:

```sh
docker build --build-arg  database_uri=mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/qualiexplore .
```

#### Build via `docker-compose`

```sh
docker compose up # from root directory
```

produces the following error:

```
qualiexplore-stack-mongo-seed-1  | 2021-11-08T15:40:31.401+0000 error parsing command line options: error parsing uri (uri): scheme must be "mongodb" or "mongodb+srv"
qualiexplore-stack-mongo-seed-1  | 2021-11-08T15:40:31.401+0000 try 'mongoimport --help' for more information
```

This implies that that the `database_uri` as build argument passed within the the service of `mongo-seed` is not being applied into the docker container.

#### Verifications

I executed:

```sh
docker compose config
```

and the environment variables from the `.env` file seem to taken into consideration for each services in the compose file

```yaml
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      DATABASE_URI: mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/qualiexplore
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: qualiexplore
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    env_file:
    - .env
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      qualiexplore_net: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 27017
      published: 27017
      protocol: tcp
  mongo-seed:
    build:
      context: ./mongo_seed
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        database_uri: mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/qualiexplore
    depends_on:
      mongo:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      DATABASE_URI: mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/qualiexplore
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: qualiexplore
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    env_file:
    - .env
    networks:
      qualiexplore_net: null
networks:
  qualiexplore_net:
    name: qualiexplore_net
    external: true
```

Is there a specific syntax that is missing in order to pass the `$DATABASE_URI` into the `CMD mongoinsert ...` command in the `Dockerfile`?

Is there any appropriate way to seed the database without having to hard-code the URI in this scenario? I am currently taking this approach, so as to make the stack configurable by only changing the Environment Variable Files and not having to tweak the internal docker-compose configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue thanks to a recent answer [on a SE Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69173690/4851126)

It essentially describes the following steps for passing build arguments from an `.env` file passed through `docker-compose.yml` file:

1. Pass the following as build argument for the `mongo-seed` service:

   ```yaml
      mongo-seed:
       env_file:
           - .env
       build:
           context: ./mongo_seed
           dockerfile: Dockerfile
           args:
               - DATABASE_URI=$DATABASE_URI
   ```
2. the `DATABASE_URI` will be an `ARG` in the `DockerFile` which will be then used as a run-time environment variable

   ```
   #..
   # Will be set through Environment Files
   ARG DATABASE_URI

   ENV DATABASE_URI ${DATABASE_URI}
   # ...
   ```
3. I had to adapt my `Dockerfile` to accept an updated version of `mongoimport` hence I had to bump the version to `mongo:5.0` and adapted the file accordingly

   ```
    FROM mongo:5.0
    # Will be set through Environment Files
    ARG DATABASE_URI
    ARG USERNAME
    ARG PASSWORD

    ENV DATABASE_URI ${DATABASE_URI}
    ENV USERNAME ${USERNAME}
    ENV PASSWORD ${PASSWORD}

    COPY factors.json /factors.json

    COPY filters.json /filters.json

    CMD mongoimport --username ${USERNAME} --password ${PASSWORD} --uri ${DATABASE_URI} --collection factors --drop --file /factors.json && \
        mongoimport --username ${USERNAME} --password ${PASSWORD} --uri ${DATABASE_URI} --collection filters --drop --file /filters.json
   ```
4. build the image from root:

   ```sh
   docker-compose build mongo-seed
   ```
5. Bring the stack up using:

   ```sh
   docker-compose up
   ```

### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
    # MongoDB
    mongo:
        container_name: mongodb
        image: mongo:latest
        env_file:
            - .env
        #volumes:
        #    - ./data:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        networks:
            - "qualiexplore_net"

    # Initial Seed to QualiExplore Database
    mongo-seed:
        env_file:
            - .env
        build:
            context: ./mongo_seed
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                - DATABASE_URI=$DATABASE_URI
                - USERNAME=$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
                - PASSWORD=$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
        depends_on:
            - mongo
        networks:
            - "qualiexplore_net"


networks:
    qualiexplore_net:
        external: true
```