# Accessing shell environment variables from docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How do you access environment variables exported in Bash from inside docker-compose?

I'm essentially trying to do what's described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69173690/247542) but I don't want to define a `.env` file.

I just want to make a call like:

```
export TEST_NAME=test_widget_abc
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p myproject up --build --exit-code-from myproject_1
```

and have it pass `TEST_NAME` to the command inside my Dockerfile, which runs a unittest suite like:

```
ENV TEST_NAME ${TEST_NAME}

CMD python manage.py test $TEST_NAME
```

My goal is to allow running my docker container to execute a specific unittest without having to rebuild the entire image, by simply pulling in the test name from the shell at container runtime. Otherwise, if no test name is given, the command will run all tests.

As I understand, you can define environment variables in a `.env` file and then reference them in your docker-compose.yml like:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  app_test:
    build:
      args:
      - TEST_NAME=$TEST_NAME
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

but that doesn't pull from the shell.

How would you do this with docker-compose?

Answer (score 1):

For the setup you describe, I'd [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/) a temporary container

```bash
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myproject
docker-compose run app_test python manage.py test_widget_abc
```

This uses all of the setup from the `docker-compose.yml` file except the `ports:`, and it uses the command you provide instead of the Compose `command:` or Dockerfile `CMD`.  It will honor `depends_on:` constraints to start related containers (you may need an entrypoint wrapper script to actually wait for them to be running).

If the test code is built into your "normal" image you may not even need special Compose setup to do this; just point `docker-compose run` at your existing application service definition without defining a dedicated service for the integration tests.

---

Since Compose does (simple) [environment variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) you could also provide the per-execution `command:` in your Compose file

```yaml
version: "3.6"
services:
  app_test:
    build: ..
    command: python manage.py $TEST_NAME # uses the host variable
```

Or, with the Dockerfile you have, pass through the host's environment variable; the `CMD` will run a shell to interpret the string when it starts up

```yaml
version: "3.6"
services:
  app_test:
    build: ..
    environment:
      - TEST_NAME # without a specific value here passes through from the host
```

These would both work with the Dockerfile and Compose setup you show in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables in your `docker-compose.yaml` will be substituted with values from the environment. For example, if I write:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app_test:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    environment:
      TEST_NAME: ${TEST_NAME}
    command:
      - env
```

Then if I export `TEST_NAME` in my local environment:

```
$ export TEST_NAME=foo
```

And bring up the stack:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating docker_app_test_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_app_test_1
app_test_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
app_test_1  | HOSTNAME=be3c12e33290
app_test_1  | TEST_NAME=foo
app_test_1  | HOME=/root
docker_app_test_1 exited with code 0
```

I see that `TEST_NAME` inside the container has received the value from my local environment.

---

It looks like you're trying to pass the environment variable into your image build process, rather than passing it in at runtime. Even if that works once, it's not going to be useful, because `docker-compose` won't rebuild your image every time you run it, so whatever value was in `TEST_NAME` *at the time the image was built* is what you would see inside the container.

It's better to pass the environment into the container at run time.

Comment: "It's better to pass the environment into the container at run time." I'm not sure what you mean. That's what I'm trying to do. Are you saying I should remove the `ENV...` statement in my Dockerfile? Will the `$TEST_NAME` reference in my `CMD` statement auto-resolve to the env variable, or will building the image cache the env variable as it's defined at build time?

Comment: I think David has provide the same answer but in more detail, so hopefully that's sufficient.