# How to find host ip address in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I want to use the host ip address in container, how should I achieve this in dockerfile way?

```
FROM my_image
ENV http_proxy <the_host_ip_address:port>
ENV https_proxy <the_host_ip_address:port>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to set the host IP address in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM my_image

ARG HOST_IP
ENV http_proxy=$HOST_IP:port
ENV https_proxy=$HOST_IP:port

# Rest of the Dockerfile goes here
```

And then when building the image, you would pass the --build-arg flag to set the HOST_IP arg:

```bash
docker build --build-arg HOST_IP=$(hostname -i) -t myimage .
```

This will set the HOST_IP arg to the IP address of the host machine during build time.

The advantage of this method is that the host IP doesn't need to be hardcoded in the Dockerfile, it is set at build time.

Comment: How to see the output of $(hostname -i)?

Comment: Just run it in your terminal:    hostname -i

Comment: That command will output the same value as what the Dockerfile is going to use

Comment: @ccd please mark the answer as complete if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any argument variables while building a docker-image and use them in the Dockerfile. For example:

```
FROM my_image
ARG host
ARG port
ENV http_proxy $host:$port
ENV https_proxy $host:$port
```

And the command for building a docker-image will look like this:

```
docker build --build-arg host=<the_host_ip_address> --build-arg port=<port> .
```

There is a useful article on the [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/dockerfile-env-variable#dynamic_values)

**UPD**

I've already found a more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34600106/22270964). Look at this.